# Python encode URL for pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, url, encode

I want to cleanup the `page_url` field under pandas dataframe `df` for example

`df`:

| page_url |
| --- |
| https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F |

Our goal is to clean it up like below:

| page_url |
| --- |
| https://www.google.com/ |

I've tried:
`df['page_url'].str.strip().replace(dict(zip(["%2F", "%3A"], ["/", ":"])),regex=True)`

It works for this example, however the dataframe `page_url` column has other values like '%2B' or other strings, just want to see if there is an alternative way to do that in Python 3 instead of writing down each string needs to be replace. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F")
# 'https://www.google.com/'
```

So what we need is

```
df['page_url'].apply(urllib.parse.unquote)
```